# Send emails based on CreatedDate + 3days?

Tags: apex, email

I wanted to send emails based on CreatedDate + 3days of that particular record. How do I achieve this requirement? Here is my code so far:

```
if(!test.isrunningtest() ){

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<String> email = new List<String>();
    EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'xxxx'];                                 
    Date d = system.today().addDays(+3);

    OrgWideAddress owp = [select id, DisplayName, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress limit 1];
    for(Group__c Group : [
        Select Id, (Select  c.Id From Committees__r c where c.Effective_Date__c <= TODAY and c.Thru_Date__c >= TODAY and c.Code__c IN ('P','N'))
        From Group__c p 
        where Id IN : lComm.keySet()AND Createddate=:d
    ]){
        if(!Member.contains(lComm.get(cGroup.Id))){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            for(Committee__c cCommittee : Group.Committee__r){}
            email.add('xxx@xxx.com');
            mail.setToAddresses(email);
            mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owp.id);
            mail.setTargetObjectId(lComm.get(Group.Id));
            mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
            mails.add(mail);
        }
```

Comment: You might consider using `Time Based Workflow Rules` instead. Otherwise you will need to look up the `Schedulable` interface.

Comment: Yeah, instead of changing the whole process, I would like to know if we can add 3 days delay for the notification in the same apex class

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: How do we add schedule class in that case? Would it be kind of a batch job which runs periodically? Or can it be on a criteria based just like created date +3 ??

Comment: You could do either. Probably better to just run a batch daily or hourly or some such. You can set almost any criteria you can imagine from a batch.

Comment: I question I had is that it should be scheduled at Createddate + 3 days. How can I achieve that? I mean how do I specify that to run based on this.

Comment: I can use the Messaging class in batch class

Comment: Also, *never* use `if (!Test.isRunnngTest())` unless you have exhausted *every alternative*. It is near the worst thing you can do to your code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are (in my order of preference):

1. Time Based Workflow
2. Process Builder Scheduled Actions
3. Batch/Scheduled Apex

The first two should be pretty straightforward to implement. If you want to batch over these records and send out emails for those created exactly three days ago, you can run a daily batch. The skeleton would look like:

```
public with sharing class MyBatch
    implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id FROM Group__c WHERE CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:3
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Group__c> records)
    {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Group__c record : records)
        {
            // add message to collection
            // query children as needed
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to schedule emails 3 days after the record is created not before that?I have another process which creates the record and once the record is created, the emails should be sent out 3 days after the created date

Comment: Yeah, hence why you query for records which were created three days ago...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Can we just use a Process builder to implement this requirement?

Comment: Yes, you can also use Time Based Workflow, which I suggested in the comments. That would be my first choice.